# Can you use a Ternary expression in an IF statement?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm just rewriting an old C++ application in C# at work so I thought I'd mess around and try to learn new things while *actual* work is slow. This is sort of redundant and defeats the purpose of an IF/ELSE statement, I suppose, but can something like this be done?

```
public static bool IsAlpha(string s, bool allowSpaces)
{
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        if (!(allowSpaces) ? (char.IsLetter(c) || c.Equals(' ')) : char.IsLetter(c))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Basically I was just trying to shorten this;

```
    alpha = (allowSpaces) ? (char.IsLetter(c) || c.Equals(' ')) : char.IsLetter(c);

    if (!alpha)
        return false;
```

If I call `IsAlpha("abcd", false)` the method seems to always return false. I'm not sure if I have a logic error in the ternary statement, or if what I'm trying to do just isn't possible. Basically just wondering if it's possible to make an IF statement evaluate one of two expressions based on `allowSpaces`'s value. But instead I think it's just evaluating `if (!allowSpace)` and returning false there.

Comment: It's possible, but it's pretty confusing. You'd be better off using ordinary boolean logic.

Comment: Isn't your logic backwards between the two choices?

Comment: @EdCottrell That's fair, and I agree. I'm just taking this time to learn what *is* possible, not necessarily what's the most readable. I'll probably leave it as the latter, I was just curious if the former was doable.

Comment: @TimSchmelter because if `alpha == true` after evaluating only the first character in the string, I don't want the function to end.

Comment: @KirkWoll Yes, you are correct. Too tired this morning. But for the test case of `"abc"` it shouldn't matter either way.

Comment: @sab669: but the method returns `true` with your input because every char is a letter in `"abc"`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter `IsAlpha("abcd", false);` does not return true with the logic I posted in my question.

Comment: @sab669: i have copy-pasted your   "I was just trying to shorten this"-code  and it always returns `true` with this sample. http://rextester.com/ZUIE11133

Comment: @TimSchmelter Right. That second bit is fine and functional. That was never up for debate. It's what I was trying to shorten, just for the sake of curiosity. It's the first bit in the first block that doesn't work and I wanted to know if it was impossible, or if I had a logic error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from using a ternary in an `if` condition - but the `!` before your ternary is applying just to `(allowSpaces)`, not to the result of the ternary. (This is because the unary operators have higher [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323.aspx) than the ternary, or *conditional*).

You need to parenthesise so the `!` applies to the result of the conditional:

```
if (!(allowSpaces ? (char.IsLetter(c) || c.Equals(' ')) : char.IsLetter(c)))
```

It might be clearer to drop the ternary:

```
if (!char.IsLetter(c) && !(allowSpaces && c.Equals(' ')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why worry about condensing this when the expansion is so simple and clear?

```
if(char.IsLetter(c)) return true;
if(allowSpace && c.Equals(' '))return true;
return false;
```

if you are wanting this to be processed inside a valiation loop, the very easy option to perform this logic is to `continue` rather than returning true

```
foreach(var c in value)
{
   if(char.IsLetter(c)) continue;
   if(allowSpace && c.Equals(' '))continue;
   return false;
}
return true;
```

It even reads exactly like what you are trying to do. 
Your valid cases are "letter" and "whitespace if explicitly allowed"

By avoiding the conjunction of terms, each of the conditions are even optimized for source control. There is likely little reason to change the logic of an alpha check, but if you were to be using business rules to perform your validation, each of those rules may be easily maintained independently.

From a performance standpoint, we're even optimized for letters and the test only performs conjunctive logic if the character is first found to not be a letter.

If you are dead set on condensing this into a one liner and removing the `continue`s, implement the conjunction of the negation of each of those two validation tests as your gate around `return false` but if you were to need to add a third, fourth, or fifth term to the validation check, you would almost have to modify the structure for legibility.

```
   foreach(var c in value)
   {
     if(!char.IsLetter(c) && !(allowSpace && c.Equals(' ')) return false;
   }
```

Comment: To answer your first question, the purpose of my question is simply "What's possible?" not "What's best?" It has nothing to do with efficiency or "shaving nanoseconds off a function" but rather sheer curiosity.

Comment: Then, *of course* a ternary is possible. But realize that you repeat your specification of the `char.IsLetter(c)` check by bouncing in and out of optional conditions. At any rate, a ternary does not improve the original code.

Comment: Well, like I said. With the method I posted, it wasn't working. I did not know if that's because I had a logic error (we all make them, after all), or if it simply wasn't possible. Simple as that.

Comment: As (hopefully) helpful advice, I *habitually* use ternary one liners to perform null checks or when I'm refactoring a serial battery of validation checks to add a third term. Be aware that using ternaries like this is a code smell. They help you implement features quickly and condense repetitive nested conditionals, but increase the complexity of identifying issues at runtime because you cannot set breakpoints on an individual check inside the condensed line.